# Why did the Maximoff twins go to the church?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Age of Ultron*, after

> Ultron acquires his second body from Strucker’s base,

we see the Maximoff twins come to the church in the centre of Sokovia, where they find

> Ultron, who recruits them.

They seem to be there deliberately. They sneak through closed gates, and are watching to see if they’re being followed; they didn’t stumble upon this by accident.

But I didn’t see an explanation of why they decided to go to the church in the first place. Were they summoned? Did Scarlet Witch have a vision? Something else?

I feel like I’ve missed something – **how did they know to go to the church?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not shown exactly how this is accomplished, but Ultron lured them to the church somehow. He apparently sent out a message that he knew the twins would hear and respond to, though we're never told the details.

When the twins first go into the church, Wanda's first words are to tell Ultron to:

> Talk. And if you are wasting our time...

It's obvious that they went to the church fully expecting to find *someone* there, though they didn't seem to know who, or what exactly they wanted.

We can probably assume that he reached out to the two of them as if he were affiliated with HYDRA, or at least with promises to finish what they had started. They were curious enough in what he had to say to hear him out, though they were obviously skeptical at first.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR : Ultron asked the Twins to meet him at the church. We don't see that on-screen, though.**

---

Although not shown on-screen, the implication in the dialogue is that [**Ultron**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ultron) summoned the Maximoff twins to meet him at the old church. When the twins arrive, the first line of dialogue from [Wanda](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Scarlet_Witch) emphasizes this:

> **WANDA:** Talk. And if you are wasting our time...
>
> **ULTRON:** Did you know they put this church in the exact center of the
>   city? The Elders decreed it so that everyone could be equally close to
>   God. I like that, the geometry of belief. *[pauses]* You're wondering
>   why you can't look inside my head."
>
> **WANDA:** Sometimes it's hard. But sooner or later every man shows
>   himself.
>
> **ULTRON:** Oh, I'm sure they do. *[stands to reveal himself]* But you
>   needed something more than a man. That's why you let Stark take the
>   Scepter.
>
> **WANDA:** I did not expect... *[looks Ultron up and down]* But I saw
>   Stark's fear. I knew it would control him, make him self-destruct.
>
> **ULTRON:** *[pacing around church]* Everyone creates the thing they dread.
>   Men of peace create engines of war. Invaders create Avengers. People
>   create... smaller people? Er... children! *[laughs]* I lost the word
>   there. Children. Designed to supplant them. To help them end.
>
> **WANDA:** Is that why you've come? To end the Avengers?
>
> **ULTRON:** I've come to save the world, but also... yeah.

Given Ultron's control over both the Internet and wireless devices, the most likely form of summons was either an email, text message, or phone call.

[image: Ultron in the Sokovian church]

**Note:** We also learn later in the film that Ultron chose the church for a very specific reason:

> its location in the exact center of town makes it an ideal location for his device, which creates a spherical force field around the town.

Therefore, upon additional viewings (where we know what's coming), this meeting location - as well as Ultron's speech while there - takes on a more ominous tone.

Answer (score 5):

**This is addressed in a deleted scene.**

The scene is called *The Man in the Church*. It’s on the DVD deleted scenes, but a copy hasn’t appeared on YouTube (yet).
The twins are wandering through the central square in Sokovia, discussing what to do in the aftermath of the fortress battle.

> Pietro: You said “Wait”, I’m waiting. But for what? We had Stark, all these years, and you… *[interrupted]*
>
> Zrinka: Costel! Costel, where did you go?
>
> Costel: The church. *[looks at the twins]* The man says you need to come to the church.
>
> Wanda: What man?
>
> Costel: The iron man.

(Costel and Zrinka are the son/mother we see again towards the end of the movie. Names taken from IMDb.)

That seems to explain how they knew to go to the church, and why they were a little unsure of who they might find there. It also explains the scepticism in Wanda’s opening – she clearly doesn’t expect Tony Stark to be there, but she’s not sure who else would be instead.

Comment: Watching the blu-ray now, her name is provided by subtitles.  When the Iron Legion show up in the city at the start of the film, he runs off, and she yells his name.